# Ways of showing that the LU decomposition of a square matrix almost always exists?

Tags: alternative-proof, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

We know that (in the measure-theoretic sense) almost all square matrices $M$ over $\mathbb R$ admit an LU decomposition: $M = LDU$. We are using the Lebesgue measure, and we may treat for each fixed $n$ the space of $n \times n$ $\mathbb R$-matrices as a measurable space.

One proof of this fact uses the fact that a necessary condition for a matrix *not* to have an LU decomposition is that:

- The matrix is singular
- Or at least one of the leading principal minors is zero.

Both conditions can be expressed as polynomial equations. Finally, we know that the zero-set of a polynomial has measure zero iff the polynomial is not the zero polynomial (as a formal expression).

Anyway, I'm asking if there are other ways of showing this.

Comment: Is the dimension of the space fixed? What measure do you consider?

Comment: Lebesgue measure. For each $n$, there is the measurable space $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$ of $n \times n$ matrices. For each of these $n$, the statement should hold.

Comment: The measurable sets are the Borel measurable ones.